# List comprehension (extracting words from a sentence)

Tags: python

I am trying to use list comprehension in order to extract only words which have characters which is greater then 3. I already made this line of code which count that words.

```
ListWord = [len(x.strip(',')) for x in 'Michael Jordan is the best basketball player of all time'.split() if len(x.strip(','))>3]

    ListWord
    Out[73]: [7, 6, 4, 10, 6, 4]
```

But now I need to see that words not only to count `е.g["Michael","Jordan","best","basketball","player","time"].` So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can't you just replace `len(x.strip(','))` with `x.strip(',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace len(x.strip(',')) with x.strip(',')

```
ListWord = [x.strip(',') for x in 'Michael Jordan is the best basketball player of all time'.split() if len(x.strip(','))>3]

print(ListWord)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your query.

```
[len(x.strip(',')) for x in 'Michael Jordan is the best basketball player of all time'.split() if len(x.strip(','))>3]
```

If we break this into components, it will be

```
[TO_RETURN for CURRENT_ITEM in LIST if CONDITION]
```

So, if you would like to return something different, replace `TO_RETURN`. In this case, `x.strip(',')` instead of `len(x.strip(','))`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using strip? Simpler to just `.split()` (that returns a list of each item) of the string, and then check the length of each item in that list:

```
list_word = [x for x in 'Michael Jordan is the best basketball player of all time'.split() if len(x)>3]
```

**Output:**

```
print(list_word)
['Michael', 'Jordan', 'best', 'basketball', 'player', 'time']
```